# UniswapV2 removeLiquidity revert ds-math-sub-underflow

Tags: uniswap

I am calling uniswapv2 remove liquidity but i am not able to get what values amountAmin and amountbmin will have . i am calling uniswapv2 router contract function for existing pool but i cant get how much  tokens i have put in that pool through any contract function

Comment: What's the transaction hash? What are the parameters of the function call?

Comment: removeLiquididty(tokenA,tokenB,liquidity,amountAmin,amountBmin,to,deadline)

Comment: I want to know what value of liquidity ,amountAmin and amountBmin needed to be pass to the function

Comment: This is a transaction hash 0xa0c72b4e2a13f87bffc0ddfd98b16643baec9642843b1bc6d802dec8cf7bc3bc

Comment: @Ismael any idea how to call the function